# converting a nested map to json for patching

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a newbie to dart and flutter: I would like to patch a map with a nested list in it, but I can't get it done. The code below returns a 400-error code.

```
Future<void> updateExerciseHistory(List<Exercise> exerciseList) async {
    exerciseList.forEach((e) async {
      try {
        final url = Uri.https(urlBase, '/exercises/${e.id}.json');
        await http.patch(
          url,
          body: json.encode({
            'history': e.history.map((key, value) => MapEntry(
                key.toIso8601String(),
                value
                    .map((s) => {
                          'id': s.id,
                          'weight': s.weight,
                          'reps': s.reps,
                          'rir': s.rir,
                          'notes': s.notes,
                        })
                    .toList())),
          }),
        );
        _userExercises
            .firstWhere((ue) => ue.id == e.id)
            .history
            .addAll(e.history);
        notifyListeners();
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    }); }

class Exercise with ChangeNotifier {
  String id;
  String name;
  Map<Muscle, double> musclesInvolved;
  Map<DateTime, List<Set>>
      history; 

  Exercise({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.musclesInvolved,
    this.history,
  });
}

class Muscle {
  final String id;
  String name;

  Muscle({this.id, this.name});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
      };
}
```

It is probably due to the return of a MapEntry. When I call the .map on a list I can  return a map, but I can't do that when I call .map on a Map (can only return a MapEntry or am I missing something)?

Does somebody have a solution for this? :-D

Thanks for any help!

Comment: May you provide value of `e` or `e.history`?

Comment: @Nima ah yes that's stupid xD. e is a class in a list. I have updated the code.